# Redux createApi-prepareHeaders

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hey I'm implmenting Redux to my project.
I want to use for API calls the new createApi tool for it.

Its working but I have one issue, when I reload the page the token that is passed via Redux is null (The login machanizem isn't working with Redux createApi), when I navigate to other routes and I return to the createApi route it fetching the data. (I also verify that via console.logging the token)

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const profileApi = createApi({
reducerPath: 'profileApi',
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
baseUrl: '(MY-API URL)/api/v1/',
prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
  const token = getState().auth.userInformation.token;

  if (token) {
    headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
  }
  console.log(token);
  return headers;
 },
}),
endpoints: (builder) => ({
getProfile: builder.query({
  query: () => 'profile/all',
  }),
 }),
});

export const { useGetProfileQuery } = profileApi;
```

In Store

```
 [profileApi.reducerPath]: profileApi.reducer,
 },
   middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
   getDefaultMiddleware().concat(profileApi.middleware),
```

Im Profile for testing

```
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetProfileQuery();

 {error ? (
    <p>error</p>
  ) : isLoading ? (
    <p>loading</p>
  ) : (
    <p>{data?.profiles?.[0]?.firstName}</p>
  )}
```

When I refreshing I only get `<p>error</p>`, when I reload or go to other path and return the Profile path I get the data.